# C# WinForms Modeless Dialog Closing

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a color control dialog (WinForm) that is modeless and sits on top of my main WinForm.  This allows adjusting of colors while interacting with the form.  For this to work, the color control dialog must be "topmost".

I'd like to close/hide this color dialog when other child dialogs are opened.  The color dialog should also close when another application gets the focus.

I added a handler for the main form's deactivate event, however this also gets called when the color control dialog gets focus itself.

Is there a way to ignore the deactivate event if my color control dialog is the one that's getting focus?  Can the deactivate event somehow tell you what is actually getting focus?

Thanks

Comment: You don't close 2nd form.  Instead you make invisible.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: It sounds like your handler for hiding the color dialog needs to be in the color dialog's Deactivate event. not the main form's.

Comment: I wonder if [Form.ActiveForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activeform?view=netframework-4.8) - _"Gets the currently active form for this application."_ - will do it, or whether it won't have been set yet

Comment: Thanks.  Here's what seems to be a workaround.  In the modeless form - add a function to see if application is active via Process.GetCurrentProcess()

In the modeless form add a Deactivate handler.   Hide the form if application is the not parent.

In the main for add a Deactivate handler.  Hide the form if the application is not the parent.

The only catch is that other modeless dialogs/forms called up from the main form will still have the modeless form on top of them.